# Bump node create wrong normals from height

Tags: shaders, height-map, bump

I attached a wave texture into a height input of a bump node, expecting to get normals corresponding to a sine surface, but instead I get normals of (0,0,1) and I can't find why.\

I checked the values by displacement as follows:

**Texture factor output:** 
The values are as expected
[image]


**Desired bump node output normals:** 
These are the normals I would like to obtained
[image]


**Actual normals values obtained by a bump node:** 
Normals Z values are always 1 - Why?
[image]


Normals X values are always 0 (and the same for Y values) - Why?
[image]

Comment: Hello I'm not sure what you're trying to do here, you need to plug a Displacement node into the Displacement input

Comment: @moonboots - I built here a graph to inspected the normal components values obtained from the bump output node. The displacement serves as "value-meter" in this context.

Comment: oh ok sorry, too complicated for me   ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The normals you're getting out of a bump node from a wave texture height are correct.

But, you cannot use these normals as the input to displacement.

Displacement affects your base normals, because it moves verts (with true displacement) or changes their normals (with bump) or both, and your base normals affect the activity of a bump node (notice the "normal" input.)  This creates a circularity.  Blender doesn't make this circularity entirely clear-- its interface suggests that displacement is only output, never input, so it's not like it's anybody's fault for missing it-- but it still exists.

Blender *always* calculates displacement before it calculates bump.  Your noodles don't matter.  It can't calculate based on a circularity, so it decides to do things this way, no matter what you tell it to do.

But, there's a really simple workaround for this.  Two workarounds, actually.  Either plug your wave texture output into your displacement (via displacement node), or plug them into a bump node and plug the normal output of that bump node into the normal input of your diffuse BSDF.

Would it be possible to do things otherwise?  Yes.  In the case of a circularity, Blender could input pre-displacement normals into the input for the bump node and calculate it from those.  It does this with generated texture coords, for good or ill (leading to a lot of confusion sometimes for people who expect coords used for displacement to match coords used for albedo.)  But it doesn't do that with normals.

Could you use GN to store pre-displacement normals and use them?  You could store them, but Blender just won't run a bump node until after it's figured displacement.  You would have to recreate the bump node functionality within GN-- probably, something just reasonably close to a bump node.  It wouldn't work with adaptive subdivision though.

Comment: Is Blender _always_ calculating displacement before bump? The bump on a plane gets distorted by the displaced geometry... also bump is visible in material preview as well, (shader-based) displacement only in rendered view. So I would have thought it is the other way round, but I admit I don't know it.

Comment: That's lights the point!!

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann I can see how you could think of the order, as pseudo-transformations, as occuring either way.  But while you can use a bump map with the normals provided by displacement, you cannot use displacement with the normals provided from a bump map.  Similar thing happens, for same reason, with the use of normal texture coords for displacement (which is more irritating than bump because it prevents live triplanar displacement.)  My conclusions are from experimentation, so no, there's no 100% certainty, I could have made an error-- but I don't believe that I did.

Answer (score 1):

Actually I do not know if you only want to get the normals or the displacement shown in the question. I'll go for the displacement, because this seems more what you want since you are using the *Displacement* socket on the *Material Output*.

Two things: Firstly, you don't need a *Bump* node for displacement, there is a dedicated *Displacement* node. You can also simply use the *Fac* output of the *Wave Texture* node and plug it into the Z socket of a *Combine XYZ* node, but the *Displacement* has some options that might be helpful like setting the *Scale* or *Midlevel* (the *Combine XYZ* node works as if *Midlevel* = 0 and *Scale* = 1). But what you need is enabling *Settings* > *Surface* > *Displacement* > *Displacement Only* (or *Displacement and Bump* if you want bump as well) in the *Material Properties*:

[image: material > displacement]

Secondly, I cannot see it in your screenshots how high the resolution of your mesh is and I suspect it is a simple plane with only four corner vertices. This is not enough if you want displacement - because for displacement you need geometry that can be displaced. Either real geometry from a subdivided mesh or using a *Subdivision Surface* modifier.

Here is an example showing you the resolution of a plane for a decent displacement result, the orange grid being the mesh resolution and the small black grid inbetween the additional subdivision by a *Subdivision Surface* modifier set to *Simple* and *Levels* = 3. On the left the *Fac* output of the *Wave Texture* is plugged into a *Combine XYZ* node, on the right it is plugged into the *Height* of a *Displacement* node. With *Midlevel* = 0 and *Scale* = 1, they produce the same result:

[image: combine vs. displacement]

Of course you can recreate the *Midlevel* and *Scale* option with a *Combine XYZ* as well: the value you enter as *Midlevel* first has to be subtracted from the *Fac* value, then you have to *Multiply* it with the *Scale* value. The order is important (at least if you want to replicate the *Displacement* node settings), first subtract, then multiply. Here I show it with *Midlevel* = 1 and *Scale* = 0.2:

[image: recreating the displacement options]

By the way, what you can do with the *Combine XYZ* node directly while you would need *Texture Coordinate* and *Mapping* nodes for the *Displacement* is moving the displaced mesh around horizontally by changing the X and Y values.

Alternatively, you could also use *Adaptive Subdivision*, which requires you to enable the *Feature Set* > *Experimental* in the *Render Properties*, then appears another setting further down in the *Render Properties* called *Subdivision* which allows you to set the *Dicing Rate* in pixels for renders and viewport, i.e. the resolution of the mesh relative in absolute pixels of the screen/image size.

Then you do not have to subdivide the plane at all, only enable *Adaptive Subdivsion* in the *Subdivision Surface* modifier. Note that these shader-based displacements are only visible in rendered view and they only work in *Cycles*.

[image: adaptive subdivision]

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. The graph is to inspect the output values of the bump node, for checking what normal values it gives when connecting wave texture into its height input. But the normal values I obtained are (0,0,1) which is strange.

Answer (score 0):

I guess there is a misconception here or a confusion between a **Vector** in general, the **Normal** of a face and what the **Displacement** does. I will simplify this in the explanations below, maybe not 100% accurate but you might get the idea.

A **Vector** in general is an $n$-tuple of elements, in Blender usually a 3-tuple holding XYZ coordinates (or a *Color* socket is basically a 3-tuple as well holding RGB values).

**Displacement** can use vectors to displace (= move) vertices in directions given by 3-tuple vectors holding X, Y and Z values moving them forwards/backwards, left/right or up/down depending on their local or otherwise submitted coordinates (for example from a different object). The main thing is: displacement moves vertices in a direction.

The **Normal** (and now I'm oversimplifying to later make clear why it seems your displacement setup cannot work) is the direction a face is pointing in and Blender differentiates between the frontside of a face and the backside. Now if you are looking on the frontside of a face, its normal is pointing towards you. Looking at the backside of the same face, the normal is pointing away from you. Normal values can range from -1 (pointing completely into the opposite direction of the according axis) to 1 (parallel to the according axis).

And here comes the problem: in your example, the displacement lets the geometry move from 0 to 1 on the Z axis in 3D space. This results in faces with normals where at the highest point the normal is pointing upwards (Z = 1) and at the lowest point as well. The faces inbetween have lower values on Z (but not 0 because there is no vertical face) and varying values on X.

In the image below I have split the normals in X and Y values, plugged them into a *Map Range* node mapping from -1/1 to 0/1 and used a *Color Ramp* to increase the contrast a bit. On the left you see the normals' X values and the Z values on the right. Faces pointing towards +X are bright (> 0.5), faces pointing towards -X are dark (< 0.5) on the left object, while faces on the right object that are more or less horizontal (pointing upwards) are very bright (Z value going towards 1):

[image: view from above]

Now I guess you expect these values to be converted into displacement by your setup. But the *Bump* node does not have a simple *Vector* output where the values which you can see above are the result. It converts the calculated height into **normals**, which can be viewed from two sides: the frontside of the face and the backside of the face. Which means, when I now change the view to the underside of the objects, the X values stay the same, but the Z values are no longer white at the maximum and minimum height - because they are pointing away from the view (I had to adjust the *Color Ramp* or it would have been completely black from the previous setting):

[image: view from below]

I admit I do not know why the *Displacement* node interprets the X values as 0 and the Z values as 1 (using a minimum? maximum? average? value), but I would strongly suspect that the *Normal* output simply does not supply valid data for *Displacement* since the values are inconsistent and depending on the view.